# ODE question from MIT OCW 18.03 problem set 2, 4(f)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question given is:

Suppose that $x(t)=e^t$ is a solution to the differential equation $t\dot x + 2x=q(t)$. What is $q(t)$? What is the general solution?

The answer given is:

If $x=e^t$ then $q(t)=t\dot x +2x = te^t+2e^t=(t+2)e^t$.
**The associated homogeneous equation is $t\dot x +2x =0$.** They then find the general solution using separation of variables, which I understand.

What I don't understand is the sentence highlighted in bold. What does it mean to have the "associated homogeneous equation"?

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/NonhomogeneousDE.aspx

Comment: Why not enter the words in bold into a search engine?

Comment: I did and I couldn't understand the first two links that showed up. but you're right -- I should have tried harder. and thanks for the link Amzoti, clearer than the other ones I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first order linear differential equation can be written in the form
$$ x' + p(t) x = q(t) $$
for functions $p(t)$ and $q(t)$. The equation is said to be homogeneous if $q(t)=0$ for all values of $t$.

If we have a differential equation $x'+p(t)x=q(t)$, then by replacing $q(t)$ with the 0 function, we can associate to it a homogeneous equation
$$x'+p(t)x=0.$$
This is called **the associated homogeneous equation** for this differential equation.

This is useful to consider, because if we can find a general solution $C_1x_1(t)$ to the associated homogeneous equation, and a **particular solution** $x_P(t)$ to the original equation, then the general solution to the differential equation is
$$x(t)=C_1x_1(t)+x_P(t).$$

In your specific example, once you have found the general solution to the associated homogeneous equation, you can use the particular solution $x(t)=e^t$ you were given, to find the general solution
$$x(t)=C_1x_1(t)+e^t$$
where $C_1x_1(t)$ is the general solution to the associated homogeneous equation.